# ASP.NET MVC selected language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I am making simple multilanguage site. Let i choose language on master page, is it normal to use `HttpCookie cookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Language"];` in HomeController to find out what language currently selected? Or there exist another,better way?

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpCookie cookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Language"];
        return View();
    }

}
```

LanguageController:

```
public class LanguageController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Language/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Change(string abbr)
    {
        if (abbr!=null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(abbr);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(abbr);
        }
        HttpCookie cookies = new HttpCookie("Language");
        cookies.Value = abbr;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookies);
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
}
```

_Layout:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @Html.ActionLink(MultiLanguages.Resources.HomeText.About, "Home")
    @Html.ActionLink("France", "Change", "Language", new { abbr = "fr" }, null)
    @Html.ActionLink("English", "Change", "Language", new { abbr = "en" }, null)
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Language"];
        if (cookies!=null && cookies.Value!=null)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookies.Value);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookies.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
        }
    }
}
```